# CSS positioning - Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, firefox4

I have a problem with the Firefox browser. You can see it [here](http://dark-project.cz/cssproblem/). Unminified version of css (using LESS): [here](http://dark-project.cz/cssproblem/style.less.css).

All browsers display it very well, but Firefox moved the form in the pink lane to the top of the page. Do you know what the problem might be?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding

`clear:both` 
on #formPruh will solve this please check if its work fine in all browser

after applying `Clear:both` on `#formPruh`

please change `margin-top:250px to 55px; in #kategories`

See this quick firebug solution shot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this in your css

```
#formPruh {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  form label {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
  }
  form table {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 60px;
    top: 210px;                 /* changed-----------        top: 15px;*/
    tr {
      height: 40px;
      border: 1px solid red;
      td.popis {
        text-align: right;
    padding-left:5px;        /* changed-----------        padding-left: 30px;*/
      }
      td.input input, td.input select {
        width: 150px;
        height: 25px;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        border: 0;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 105%;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to **clear** your **floated** DIV (logo, actions, user). Write like this:

```
#formPruh {
    clear: both;
    height: 120px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: applying anything will coz another div to go down coz OP applied margin-top:250px on one of his div so i mentioned in my answer solution for both..

Comment: and how come you post things so fast :( yahan main question smjhta hu wahan tumhara answer post ho jata hai.:(

Comment: it's all about knowledge nothing else. mujhe jitna ata hai utna mai bata deta hu